# Summary of ASP.NET MVC 3 changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I know there is already a "MVC 3 releases notes" page from Microsoft which explain the new features in MVC 3. However, this list is very long and i am pretty sure someone can summarize the new features (not full explanation of new features) in a short manner. This would help not only me but others (such MVC 2 users) that are looking to get into MVC 3 without losing much time.

So can anyone bring up a summary of ASP.NET MVC 3 changes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/01/16/asp-net-mvc-3-new-features.aspx